# iOS: Twilo call getting disconnect after few seconds in background or lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, voip

**Description**
I am using Twilio Programmable Video SDK for audio video calls.
This feature was working fine 4-5 months back.
If we pick the call from lock screen then it gets disconnect when my device screen gets dim after few seconds.
However if we pick call when the app is foreground then it works well.
If we pick call and then put the app in background then also call is getting disconnect after few seconds
This happens with audio video call both.

**Steps to Reproduce**
Lock Device.
Receive Call from some other device.
Pick call.
Call will start and audio will come fine.
After few seconds, Device Screen will get Dim or off.
Call will disconnect, but on the other hand call is getting continue.
On Debugger this message is coming.
Message From Debugger: Terminated due to signal 9.
This happens with audio video call both

**Expected Behavior**
Call should work fine for longer time.

**Reproduces How Often**
98%

**Logs**
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9.

**Programmable Video SDK**
3.7.0 via CocoaPods

**Xcode**
12

**iOS Version**
14.1

**iOS Device**
iPhone 7

**App Capability Background Modes**
Audio
Location
VOIP
Background Fetch
Remote Notifications
Background Processing

Comment: Thank you for your reporting a bug.  But this isn't Twilio.  What's your question, anyway?

Comment: @ElTomato I can understand that this is not Twilio. But the question here is call is getting disconnect when I put it in background in iOS 14. But it works while in foreground. So I would like to ask if it is related to any update in iOS. As this feature was working in previous iOS..